# Why does this complex generics example not compile with Java 7, (but does with Java 8), and how can I work around it?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-7

Here's the code. The errors and warnings for both Java 7 and 8 are included in comments.

It is possible to change the signature of `takeCollection(...)` so that callers have a way to call it and pass `SubRoot`/`Foo`/`Bar` collections and compile this both against Java 7 and 8, while NOT having to refer in the method signature specifically to `SubRoot`/`Foo`/`Bar` types via overloading (there may many of these, some in dependent projects not visible to this one)?  If so, how?

```
package generics;

import java.util.Collection;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Cannot change this (start)
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
interface Root<F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>> {}
class     Foo <F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>> implements Root<F,B> {}
class     Bar <F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>> implements Root<F,B> {}

interface SubRoot extends Root<SubFoo, SubBar> {}
class     SubFoo  extends Foo <SubFoo, SubBar> implements SubRoot {}
class     SubBar  extends Bar <SubFoo, SubBar> implements SubRoot {}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// End of cannot change block.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class GenericsTest {

  <R extends Root<F,B>, F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>>
  void takeOne(R one) {}

  // The following method signature can be changed a bit, but it has to accept a collection
  // of Roots, or ANY of its subtypes.
  <R extends Root<F,B>, F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>, C extends Collection<R>>
  void takeCollection(C collection) {}

  // ------------------------------------------
  // Test/illustration code that compiles well
  // ------------------------------------------

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") // Warnings understood
  void testOneRoot1(Root root, Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    takeOne(root);
    // Java 1.7 and 1.8 agree about the warning, as expected.
    //
    // generics\GenericsTest.java:35: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method takeOne in class GenericsTest is applied to given types
    //    takeOne(root);
    //           ^
    //  required: R
    //  found: Root
    //  where R,F,B are type-variables:
    //    R extends Root<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B>takeOne(R)
    //    F extends Foo<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B>takeOne(R)
    //    B extends Bar<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B>takeOne(R)

    takeOne(foo);
    // Java 1.7 and 1.8 agree about the warning, as expected.
    //
    // generics\GenericsTest.java:48: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method takeOne in class GenericsTest is applied to given types
    //    takeOne(foo);
    //           ^
    //  required: R
    //  found: Foo
    //  where R,F,B are type-variables:
    //    R extends Root<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B>takeOne(R)
    //    F extends Foo<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B>takeOne(R)
    //    B extends Bar<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B>takeOne(R)

    takeOne(bar);
    // Java 1.7 and 1.8 agree about the warning, as expected.
    //
    // generics\GenericsTest.java:61: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method takeOne in class GenericsTest is applied to given types
    //    takeOne(bar);
    //           ^
    //  required: R
    //  found: Bar
    //  where R,F,B are type-variables:
    //    R extends Root<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B>takeOne(R)
    //    F extends Foo<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B>takeOne(R)
    //    B extends Bar<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B>takeOne(R)
  }

  <R extends Root<F,B>, F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>>
  void testOneRoot2(R root, F foo, B bar) {
    takeOne(root); // All fine
    takeOne(foo);  // All fine
    takeOne(bar);  // All fine
  }

  void testOneSubRoot(SubRoot subRoot, SubFoo subFoo, SubBar subBar) {
    takeOne(subRoot); // All fine
    takeOne(subFoo);  // All fine
    takeOne(subBar);  // All fine
  }

  void testRootCollectionRaw(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Collection<? extends Root> collection) {
    takeCollection(collection);
    // Java 1.7 quiet (not expected). Java 1.8 produces a warning, as expected:
    //
    //  generics\GenericsTest.java:89: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method takeCollection in class GenericsTest is applied to given types
    //      takeCollection(collection);
    //                    ^
    //    required: C
    //    found: Collection<CAP#1>
    //    where C,R,F,B are type-variables:
    //      C extends Collection<R> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      R extends Root<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      F extends Foo<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      B extends Bar<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //    where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    //      CAP#1 extends Root from capture of ? extends Root
 }

  // --------------------------------------------
  // Test/illustration code that does NOT compile
  // --------------------------------------------

  <R extends Root<F,B>, F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>>
  void testRootCollection1(Collection<? extends R> collection) {
    takeCollection(collection);
    //  JDK 1.8 quiet (as expected). JDK 1.7 yields an error (not expected):
    //
    //  generics\GenericsTest.java:112: error: invalid inferred types for R#1,F#1,B#1; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    //      takeCollection(collection);
    //                    ^
    //      inferred: CAP#1
    //      bound(s): Root<CAP#2,CAP#3>
    //    where R#1,F#1,B#1,C,R#2,F#2,B#2 are type-variables:
    //      R#1 extends Root<F#1,B#1> declared in method <R#1,F#1,B#1,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      F#1 extends Foo<F#1,B#1> declared in method <R#1,F#1,B#1,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      B#1 extends Bar<F#1,B#1> declared in method <R#1,F#1,B#1,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      C extends Collection<R#1> declared in method <R#1,F#1,B#1,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      R#2 extends Root<F#2,B#2> declared in method <R#2,F#2,B#2>testRootCollection1(Collection<? extends R#2>)
    //      F#2 extends Foo<F#2,B#2> declared in method <R#2,F#2,B#2>testRootCollection1(Collection<? extends R#2>)
    //      B#2 extends Bar<F#2,B#2> declared in method <R#2,F#2,B#2>testRootCollection1(Collection<? extends R#2>)
    //    where CAP#1,CAP#2,CAP#3 are fresh type-variables:
    //      CAP#1 extends R#2 from capture of ? extends R#2
    //      CAP#2 extends Foo<CAP#2,CAP#3> from capture of ?
    //      CAP#3 extends Bar<CAP#2,CAP#3> from capture of ?
  }

  <R extends Root<F,B>, F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>>
  void testRootCollection2(Collection<R> collection) {
    takeCollection(collection);
    //  JDK 1.8 quiet (as expected). JDK 1.7 yields an error (not expected):
    //
    //  generics\GenericsTest.java:136: error: invalid inferred types for R#1,F#1,B#1; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    //      takeCollection(collection);
    //                    ^
    //      inferred: R#2
    //      bound(s): Root<CAP#1,CAP#2>
    //    where R#1,F#1,B#1,C,R#2,F#2,B#2 are type-variables:
    //      R#1 extends Root<F#1,B#1> declared in method <R#1,F#1,B#1,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      F#1 extends Foo<F#1,B#1> declared in method <R#1,F#1,B#1,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      B#1 extends Bar<F#1,B#1> declared in method <R#1,F#1,B#1,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      C extends Collection<R#1> declared in method <R#1,F#1,B#1,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      R#2 extends Root<F#2,B#2> declared in method <R#2,F#2,B#2>testRootCollection2(Collection<R#2>)
    //      F#2 extends Foo<F#2,B#2> declared in method <R#2,F#2,B#2>testRootCollection2(Collection<R#2>)
    //      B#2 extends Bar<F#2,B#2> declared in method <R#2,F#2,B#2>testRootCollection2(Collection<R#2>)
    //    where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    //      CAP#1 extends Foo<CAP#1,CAP#2> from capture of ?
    //      CAP#2 extends Bar<CAP#1,CAP#2> from capture of ?
  }

  void testSubRootCollection1(Collection<SubRoot> collection) {
    takeCollection(collection);
    //  JDK 1.8 quiet (as expected). JDK 1.7 yields an error (not expected):
    //
    //  generics\GenericsTest.java:158: error: invalid inferred types for R,F,B; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    //      takeCollection(collection);
    //                    ^
    //      inferred: SubRoot
    //      bound(s): Root<CAP#1,CAP#2>
    //    where R,F,B,C are type-variables:
    //      R extends Root<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      F extends Foo<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      B extends Bar<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      C extends Collection<R> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //    where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    //      CAP#1 extends Foo<CAP#1,CAP#2> from capture of ?
    //      CAP#2 extends Bar<CAP#1,CAP#2> from capture of ?
  }

  void testSubRootCollection2(Collection<? extends SubRoot> collection) {
    takeCollection(collection);
    //  JDK 1.8 quiet. JDK 1.7 yields an error:
    //
    //  generics\GenericsTest.java:177: error: invalid inferred types for R,F,B; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    //      takeCollection(collection);
    //                    ^
    //      inferred: CAP#1
    //      bound(s): Root<CAP#2,CAP#3>
    //    where R,F,B,C are type-variables:
    //      R extends Root<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      F extends Foo<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      B extends Bar<F,B> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //      C extends Collection<R> declared in method <R,F,B,C>takeCollection(C)
    //    where CAP#1,CAP#2,CAP#3 are fresh type-variables:
    //      CAP#1 extends SubRoot from capture of ? extends SubRoot
    //      CAP#2 extends Foo<CAP#2,CAP#3> from capture of ?
    //      CAP#3 extends Bar<CAP#2,CAP#3> from capture of ?
  }
}
```

Comment: Yikes, that's some scary-looking generics. Could you maybe cut it down to just ask about one of these walls of error text, rather than all of these?

Comment: I also think that you are expecting quite a lot ...

Comment: Most errors are the same. I added them here for completeness as some people complained they didn't see them when I originally asked them. I have reduced the problem down to the minimum - top 27 lines are all that matters really, the rest is just illustrating the problem in various ways.

Comment: Replacing all rawtypes in your code with wildcarded types (eg. `Foo` with `Foo<?,?>`) removes all warnings, at least in Java 8.

Comment: That is fine, I am not concerned about these - I noted them in comments as expected. What was unexpected is that Java 7 does not issue all the warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the compilation errors go away for me if I change the signature of `takeCollection` to:

```
<R extends Root<F,B>, F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>>
void takeCollection(Collection<? extends R> collection) {}
```

There are unchecked/unsafe operations warnings, though, all related to raw types.

Comment: That actually works! Can anyone explain why is that different?

Comment: "That actually works!" Don't sound so surprised.

Comment: :) Well, I tried many things but not quite that variant. Why would this mean anything different to a compiler than what is shown above? Isn't void accept(P p) supposed to act the same as <Q extends P> void accept(Q q)?

Comment: Not sure. I can imagine it has something to do with the compiler not liking that it can't calculate an actual bound for `C`, because it's being passed an upper-bounded collection. Whilst not an intellectually satisfying response, "just accept that it works" is a pragmatic response; add it to your repertoire of tricks to try next time you're in generics hell.

Comment: Oh, I already applied it pragmatically :) .... But I would like to learn why this is an issue so that I can prevent it, deal better with situations like this. As it is I can't be sure whether I just moved the problem elsewhere (this is a library that unknown developers do and will use for unknown code - I don't want to break their code). It means that I may have to create method variants (overload if possible) to cover all the cases.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the signatures like follows:

```
void takeOne(Root<?,?> one) {}

void takeCollection(Collection<? extends Root<?,?>> collection) {}

void testOneRoot1(Root<?,?> root, Foo<?,?> foo, Bar<?,?> bar) {}

<R extends Root<F,B>, F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>>
void testOneRoot2(R root, F foo, B bar) {}

void testOneSubRoot(SubRoot subRoot, SubFoo subFoo, SubBar subBar) {}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void testRootCollectionRaw(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Collection<? extends Root> collection) {
   takeCollection((Collection<? extends Root<?,?>>)collection);    
}      

void testRootCollection1(Collection<? extends Root<?,?>> collection) {}

void testRootCollection2(Collection<? extends Root<?,?>> collection) {}
```

Your code should compile using this signatures for both Java 7 and Java 8 without errors or warnings. There are several places in your code where it makes sense to replace generic type parameters with wildcards. For example, `<R extends Root<F,B>, F extends Foo<F,B>, B extends Bar<F,B>>
  void takeOne(R one) {}` is almost equivalent to `void takeOne(Root<?,?> one) {}`, because how to bind `F` and `B` is already defined by the signature of `Root`. `testRootCollectionRaw` is a special case, because it features a rawtype as upperbound. I would rather solve this case with an unchecked cast in the `testRootCollectionRaw` method than by adapting the `takeCollection` signature for it to work.

The reason why your original code does not compile for Java 7 is that type inference in Java 7 is not as advanced as in Java 8. Java 8 will consider the target type of an expression on type inference. Generally, it is a good idea to replace explicit type parameters with wildcards where it is possible. A side effect of practicing this is that Java 7 has an easier time dealing with wildcards than with explicit type parameters in generic methods.

Comment: testRootCollectionRaw is only an illustration, I don't really care about raw types. Wildcards aren't entirely equivalent, though.